# React - How to clear the value of a React-Select when another React-Select changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I have two components side-by-side which are `React-Select` drop-down list components:

```
<SelectField 
  options={props.directories}
  placeholder="Directory"
  onChange={props.onDirectoriesChange}
  value={props.directoryCodeName}
  isClearable={true}
  />

<SelectField 
  options={props.subDirectories}
  placeholder="Sub Directory"
  onChange={props.onSubDirectoryChange}
  value={props.subDirectoryCodeName}
  isClearable={true}

  />
```

Now, when I select a value in the first drop-down, the second drop-down is populated according to what has been selected in the first one. When I select an option in the second drop-down then change the option in the first drop-down, the list of options have changed in the second drop down, which is great. However, the current value of the second drop down is not cleared. **What is the best way to clear the value of the second drop-down?**

First thing that comes to mind is to put some code in the `onChange` handlers below:

```
const onDirectoriesChangeHandler = (props: WrappedFieldsProps) => (
  selectedDirectories: IOption<string>
) => {
  props.directoryCodeName.input.onChange(fromJS(selectedDirectories));
};

const onSubDirectoryChangeHandler = (props: WrappedFieldsProps) => (
  selectedSubDirectories: IOption<string>
) => {
  props.subDirectoryCodeName.input.onChange(fromJS(selectedSubDirectories));
};
```

But I have reached a dead-end and I am thinking of "Lifting State Up", unless there is a way to do this using React-Select's attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your instinct is correct - you should be "lifting state up". There is probably a way to do this without, but it will likely cause some other problems later on.

Presumably your two `Select` components are contained in some other parent component? You could use the `onChange` function to set clear the value of the second input via `setState()`, something like:

```
onChangeSelectOne(value) {
  this.setState({
    directoryCodeName: value,
    subDirectoryCodeName: null
  })
}
```

Then refer to state where you define the two `Select`s:

```
<SelectField 
  options={props.directories}
  placeholder="Directory"
  onChange={props.onDirectoriesChange}
  value={state.directoryCodeName} // notice state!
  isClearable={true}
  />

<SelectField 
  options={props.subDirectories}
  placeholder="Sub Directory"
  onChange={props.onSubDirectoryChange}
  value={state.subDirectoryCodeName} // notice state!
  isClearable={true}
  />
```

One last step is to populate the component's state in its constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    directoryCodeName: props.directoryCodeName,
    subDirectoryCodeName: props.subDirectoryCodeName
  }
}
```

Calling `setState()` will trigger a re-render of your component, updating the dropdown to the value you've set.